# Interpolation doesn't work in pug value attribute

Tags: express, pug

I am trying to use the below markup to autopopulate the form.

```
textarea.form-control(rows='5',id='description' name='description', value='#{product.description}')
```

where product is the variable from js file.But the form doesn't autopopulate the values

route:

```
router.get('/update/:id', function(req, res) {
  productApi.getProductById(req.params.id, function(err, product) {

    res.render('crud/update', {product: product});
  });
});
```

json:

```
products: [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "description": "Tasty cookies"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "description": "delicious candies"
    }]
```

Comment: Please also post the route and JSON used to call the pug template.  All three have to match in order to successfully render a form.

Comment: Sorry for insufficient details..I have updated now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to output the form element:

```
textarea.form-control(rows='5' id=product.id name='description')= product.description
```

Notes:

- When you put an `=` directly after an attribute what comes next is evaluated as an expression so you can just drop a variable name in there (without quotes)
- When you're inside an inline expression the interpolation tags won't work (`#{...}` and `!{...}`) so just use plain variable names or [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (template literals don't work in IE)
- Commas are optional in pug, it will insert them where necessary in the output but you can leave them in if you like them

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Now i can see the values populated when i inspect it.But however the form fields are not populated.Why?

Comment: I just edited the answer to fix that.  textareas don't use a value, they use inner html.

Comment: @JensPanis this would be better asked as a separate question with more details.